# Why doesn't my Bootstrap v4 navbar show properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There should be a nice navbar with a few links and a button, but there is only a narrow strip without any text inside. Any ideas what may cause this? A fiddle with code and result https://jsfiddle.net/chd34xoa/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark" style="background-color:red">
        <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navTog"></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="navTog"><span class="navbar-brand">Logo</span>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-md-right">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no container class.

Comment: @serkandemirel0420 I copied the example code from the udemy course I'm trying to follow and it worked just fine there

Comment: Try adding "container" class to body tag.

Comment: The bar isn't full width now. Nothing changed, besides the strip getting narrower with two blank spaces on the sides.

Comment: To make it full, wrap in .container-fluid div.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Correct explaination

You didn't add the container class

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark" style="">
     <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
          </div>
        </nav>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to make this?
[image]

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin:0;padding: 0;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" style="background-color:#ff0100">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This, but full width

Comment: I am edited code. If you make full width you user container-fluid and margin:0;padding0

Comment: It doesn't work after setting container-fluid, returned to the red stripe state.

Comment: Yeah, your code works, I can't implement it into mine

Comment: in that case up my answer